# Can we play same Minecraft world on two different Playstation accounts

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

Me and my friends share a Playstation and we want to play in one Minecraft world, but I don't want to play split screen and I don't want to use there Playstation account to get the world. Is there a way that we can all play the same world (I don't mean a seed, I want it to function the same as us playing split screen without having the play at the same time) on different Playstation accounts. Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Realms](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/realms) to host your world instead of it being local to the PS4. Subscriptions start at $3.99 a month for a you plus two friends server:

> ...Your Realm is a private persistent world, safely stored in the cloud....
>
> Pricing:
>
> | - | REALMS | REALMS PLUS REALMS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Monthly subscription rate (recurring)* | 3.99 USD | 7.99 USD |
> | Number of players | You + 2 players | You + 10 players |

My family and I utilize Realms to share across not only the local system, but between homes so that everyone can contribute to the world. The advantage to this approach is:

- The world is always available.

  - So long as you keep your subscription current.
- There are backups, so if something breaks, you can restore your world.
- Multiple people can play, without the owner being online.
- You can have up-to, three worlds shared on a Realms server.

If you're not opposed to paying a monthly subscription, using Realms is a cheap and easy way to share worlds not only across the device, but across the world if you so choose.

---

<sub>***Note**: See the full pricing table and feature list [here](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/realms/bedrock). Pricing and availability are subject to change but are accurate as of 30 JUL 2021.*</sub>

Comment: This answer is what I was considering as well, but it frustrates me slightly that the easiest way to access this world on the same console through 2 different accounts is to pay 3.99 a month.

Comment: Agreed, why should I pay (though it is cheep) to play online when I am standing next to the person I want to play with. Smh.

Comment: @MikeZ. I concur entirely, and there's nothing wrong with that stance. But, it might be the *only* way to accomplish it. I actually searched for a way to do it without Realms for about a month before I bit the bullet.