# Is it possible to transfer a world to mobile(IOS) from PS4?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I created a world on my PS4 and have spent many hour’s on it and now don’t have the time to play. Is there any way to transfer that same world to my mobile(IOS)? Both my PS4 and mobile use the same Microsoft account.

Comment: I believe [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321635/how-to-share-worlds-between-platforms-with-minecraft-better-together) question answers yours.

Comment: My [answer to this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/389299/274742) can also be of assistance.

Comment: Casting close vote as duplicate ...

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to do this would be through realms. Make a realm, upload the world, and download it. Theoretically you could download the ipads game files in to a computer, and upload it to the Playstation, but this is impossible if you dont know what your doing.

Answer (score -1):

I’m pretty sure you can only do it if you have a realm which costs money. I’ll let you know if I find another way to do so. (and a free way)

Comment: This has already been mentioned in a [previous answer here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/390962/4797) and does not add to that answer. As per the [Help Center on what answers are deleted](/help/deleted-answers) and the meta post, [How do we handle duplicate answers?](//meta.arqade.com/q/4971/4797) - this answer could be deleted.